# ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, 64-bit, activex

Using Windows 7 64-bit. I'm getting error "ActiveX component can't create object". All worked well under WinXp. I am logged on as an Administrator. The ActiveX is a 32-bit component.

I can access the ActiveX component (with CreateObject), without errror, from a vb program.

But when I load my asp page using IE8, the vb script portion errors when trying to execute a CreateObject statement.

At first I thought the user needed elevated privileges but now it seems like vbs does not have the privileges to access the ActiveX component. I have also read that the 64-bit vbs interpreter can not execute a 32-bit activex component.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX component is a DLL. 64-bit host process can't load 32-bit DLL and vice versa. So first of all you need to target this issue, then approach security issues (if you keep having them).

There's a way to load the 32-bit ActiveX from 64-bit process by creating an outproc server, but I don't know details.

Comment: I'm using an outproc server (ActiveX Exe). This component is set to Run as Administrator. I also included a Manifest file in the same folder where this component resides. The vbs script errors when trying to access this component. The actual script error is "Object doesn't support this property or method."